# Outputting UTF-8 special characters with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am trying to `JSON_encode` data from a MySQL database. The characters in the DB are as should.

For example, some of the data contains this: *è*

When I print out to the browser, this is what I get for all items that have special characters:

```
{"category":null}
```

Here is the very basic watered down version of the code I am using to test:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM master_cat ORDER BY category ASC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        $output[] = $row;

print(json_encode($output));
```

How can I get actual data to appear in browser when I am reading the JSON on the web page and not `null`?

Comment: That is a very basic watered down version if you can get `$output[] = $row` and `json_encode($output)` resulting in `{"category":null}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `utf8_encode` on the text fields, but can you check that the data is, indeed, there? Maybe output the data in HTML instead of JSON-encoding it? Because on my system UTF8 is either recognized, gives error, or some characters are truncated.

NULL smells of database data missing.

If the data is there, then:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM master_cat ORDER BY category ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);

print(json_encode($output));
```

You might want to specify explicitly the MIME type and charset too:

```
Header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

see [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

Comment: I do know the data is there.  If I replace, for example è with e, it shows up.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: Also make sure the MySQL is set to be in UTF-8 mode or similar.

Comment: Well spotted, @YannRamin! Adding to answer.

Comment: Interesting, my database shows this item `Tèst` and now my output is not `null` but `{"category":"T\u00c3\u00a8st"}`  (I used your code above)

Comment: Which seems to be correct. The "è" is encoded as a two-byte UTF8, C3 A8, which gets JSON-encoded as \u00c3 \u00a8. Now the client must interpret it. You're almost there! :-D

Comment: @Iserni the client being ... the browser?

Comment: Yes, the Javascript on the browser (or any other JSON client). It will decode \u00c3\u00a8 back into "è".

Answer (score 2):

You should use  [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) to encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.
In this case:

```
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```